# Concurrent Event Processing Problems

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, sfml

I just started learning multi-threading in general and I know that the example application - I am working on - might even decrease in performance when using threads. The used Compiler is *GCC4.7* with following flags:
*-std=c++0x -g -O3 -Wall*

Therefore I am working with C++11 and use the std::thread implementation. In general I try to develop cross-platform, so I develop on Windows on University Computers using GCC4.7 as well and Ubuntu/Mac OSX on my home machine. To be able to handle Window creation cross-platform I use the SFML-library (2.0).

Here the simplified CApp Class and related functions:

```
class CApp
{
public:
    //! Constructor.
    CApp(void);
    //! Deconstructor.
    ~CApp(void);

    /* Public Functions: */
    //! Initializer function, needs to be called before Run-Function to allocate everything and set everything up.
    bool Initialize(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, char* title, bool vsync, CState* startState);
    void Run(void); //!< Starts the game-loop
private:
    void ProcessEvent(sf::Event event);

    sf::RenderWindow*   m_pWindow;      //!< window instance
    std::vector<std::thread> m_threads;
};
```

In general my application is a small OpenGL Demo Scene, that should be heavily multi-threaded to be able to benchmark and compare where multi-threading is suited and where it is not.

The implementations of the concerned functions:

```
void CApp::Run(void)
{
    while (m_pWindow->IsOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (m_pWindow->PollEvent(event))
        {
            m_threads.push_back(std::thread(&CApp::ProcessEvent, this, event)); 
        } 
        // ...
        m_threads.clear();
    }
}

void CApp::ProcessEvent(sf::Event event)
{
    if (event.Type == sf::Event::Closed)
        m_pWindow->Close();
    if (event.Type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) 
    {
        if (event.Key.Code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
            m_pWindow->Close();
    }
}
```

The runtime error I get is simply an Abort trap: 6 on the first frame:
_"terminate called without an active exception - Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007fff8fdf4ce2 in __pthread_kill ()"_

If I outcomment the thread creation and just call ProcessEvent in the current thread, no problem occurs, so the problem must be thread related.

SFML isn't all in all thread-safe, so I assume the problem is the m_pWindow-Pointer or the event as function argument itself, but how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Try very hard indeed to not continually create, terminate and destroy threads.  Such designs are, err.. 'less than optimal', due to overheads and prone to errors and lockups.  Benchmarking such a design is misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before clearing the vector and such deleting all the threads, you should definitely wait for all threads to finish:

```
void CApp::Run(void)
{
    while (m_pWindow->IsOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (m_pWindow->PollEvent(event))
        {
            m_threads.push_back(std::thread(&CApp::ProcessEvent, this, event)); 
        } 

    for(auto& i : m_threads)
      i.join();

    m_threads.clear();
   }
}
```

In addition, when you are using GCC I would recommend to compile with the `-pthread` option.